# Angular binding data array of object

Tags: angular

how to binding this data

```
    export const CEK: Cek[] = [
  {
    id : 1,
    name : 'one',
    arr : [{lat : 123, long:3212}]
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'two',
    arr : [{lat : 123, long:3212}]
  },
];
```

i have try binding data like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datacek">
        <td> {{data.id}} </td>
        <td> {{data.name}}</td>
        <td> {{data.arr[lat]}} {{data.arr[long]}} </td>
    </tr>
```

^ data.arr[lat] or data.arr[lat] is not showing anything

or i have try this way

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datacek">
        <td> {{data.id}} </td>
        <td> {{data.name}}</td>
        <td> {{data.arr}}</td>
    </tr>
```

and the result only showing `[object Object]`

any idea how to binding my case of data ?

Comment: What is `datacek`?

Comment: yes i think it shoudl be Cek!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `arr` property as **object** then it will work with your existing templating.

```
export const CEK: Cek[] = [
  {
    id : 1,
    name : 'one',
    arr : {lat : 123, long:3212}
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'two',
    arr : {lat : 123, long:3212}
  },
];
```

Otherwise use index for `arr` **array**

```
<td> {{data.arr[0].lat}} {{data.arr[0].long}} </td>
```

> You declared the property as array and using it like an object.
>   This is the problem.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works @ShaugiMuhammad

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
<td> {{data.arr[0].lat}} {{data.arr[0].long}} </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datacek">
    <td> {{data.id}} </td>
    <td> {{data.name}}</td>
    <td> {{data.arr[0].lat}} {{data.arr[0].long}} </td>
</tr>
```

Let me know is it solved your issue.